# Trim password in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I need to trim password from login form. That's it. What is the simplest way?

Comment: You have to use JavaScript or replace formlogin filter to do that. Looking at the code of org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, it seems username is trimmed but not the password.

Comment: Tha's what i have used - my overriden UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFi‌​lter version, overriden protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {..}

Comment: Nice to know that you have solved the problem.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for you comment, Ritesh. The other problem is that it is not really simple way - to introduce this filter is a lot of work.

Comment: I would not recommend but there are 2 more options to do this with default XML configuration: (1) Build spring security code yourself after making changes in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFi‌​lter (add JIRA issue and hope it would be added in future release), and (2) Add your own HttpServletRequestWrapper at the top of filter chain. This wrapper will trim password when getParameter is invoked.